# Does iOS support the react native library

Tags: ios, react-native

I am developing a iOS application where I need to develop the functionality like a react native library is this possible I am using react native library in my native application.

Comment: You can't just include a react native library in a standard iOS project, the build system is different

Answer (score 0):

$ npm install  --save

use this command to automatically add all the react native libraries be it an android application or an IOS application.
In case you want to do it manually,
please refer the link below which gives you the step by step pictorial representation on how to do it-
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking-libraries-ios